# Print mac address to file

Tags: linux, shell, ethernet, mac-address

With a bash script, can I read the mac address of my eth0 and print it to a file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ifconfig` will output information about your interfaces, including the MAC address:

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:289748093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:232688719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3264330708 (3.0 GiB)  TX bytes:4137701627 (3.8 GiB)
          Interrupt:17
```

The `HWaddr` is what you want, so you can use `awk` to filter it:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}'
00:11:22:33:44:55
```

Redirect that into a file:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' > filename
```

Comment: You can also use th `ip` command: `/sbin/ip link show eth0`.

Comment: @Keith I don't have that command, I'm not sure which package it's in; I think `ifconfig` is fairly standard

Comment: @Michael On Linux anyway, it is the [preferred tool](http://lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.IPROUTE2.WHY). In fact you must use to configure some advanced features. But ifconfig lives on...

Comment: The international approach is `LC_ALL=C ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}'`, because the output might be localized, not matching 'HWaddr'. LC_ALL=C uses the international standard.

Comment: @user Ah, cool. As far as I know it'll always be the first line, so you could just get away with `awk '{print $NF; exit}'` too

Comment: Yes, if you're the AWK-type. I'm the sed-type, but would here prefer an `| head -n 1` then.

Comment: I know this is Unix & Linux community but this also works on QNX 6.5.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a modern Linux method:

```
ip -o link show dev eth0 | grep -Po 'ether \K[^ ]*'
```

It's modern in that `ifconfig` has [long been deprecated](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) in favour of `ip` from the `iproute2` package, and that `grep` has the `-P` option for perl regular expressions for the [zero-width positive look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3C=pattern%29-%5CK).

`grep -o` is nice for text extraction. `sed` is traditionally used for that but I find the perl-style zero-width assertions clearer than a sed substitution command.

You don't actually need the `-o` (oneline) option to `ip`, but I prefer to use it when extracting network information since I find it cleaner having one record per line. If you're doing more complicated matches or extractions (usually with `awk`), `-o` is essential for a clean script, so for the sake of consistency and a common pattern, I always use it.

Edit: Updating 10 years later: `ip` now has the `-j` flag for JSON output, and when combined with `jq`, it provides a more robust and readable command pipeline:

```
ip -j link show dev eth0 | jq -r '.[0].address'
```

The `-r` flag to `jq` makes it output a raw string instead of a quoted (JSON) string.

Comment: @michelemarcon: This does not use perl. It uses recent GNU grep and grep has an option for using perl-style regular expressions.

Comment: I have busybox grep, thanks however for the clarification. +1

Answer (score 5):

```
#! /bin/sh

/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /HWaddr\s+(\S+)/' >file
```

There are other tools that could cut the MAC address out of `ifconfig`'s output, of course.  I just like Perl.

Comment: I don't have perl on my system... :( However, +1

Answer (score 0):

Using `ip -br link show eth0` will print something like this:

```bsh
$ ip -br link show eth0 
eth0             UP             85:e2:62:9c:b2:02 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

You only need the 3rd column, so:

```bsh
$ ip -br link show eth0 | awk '{ print $3 }'
85:e2:62:9c:b2:02
$ ip -br link show eth0 | awk '{ print $3 }' > file
```